# Packet forwarding for L2TP/IPSec VPN

Tags: ubuntu, l2tp, routeros

I have 2 Server:

Server 1: MikroTik RouterOS  (Setting up L2TP vpn server) [out of my country]

Server 2: Fresh Ubuntu 20.04 OS [in my country]

I can't connect to Server 1 via L2TP connection (protocol blocked by ISP for out country servers), but I don't have limitation to connect Server 2 via L2TP or other protocols...

My scenario is run packet forwarding on Server 2 and use L2TP connection of Server 1, but change IP address Server 1 to IP address server 2 in VPN connection.

It will work?